# How can I add folder url in cloudinary nodejs

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to add a new path to folder I created on cloudinary.

Here is my `profilesAPI.js`:

```
router.post("/upload/image", function (req, res, next) {
  const dUri = new Datauri();

  const dataUri = (req) =>
    dUri.format(path.extname(req.name).toString(), req.data);

  if (req.files !== undefined && req.files !== null) {
    const { file, id } = req.files;

    const newFile = dataUri(file).content;

    cloudinary.uploader
      .upload(newFile)
      .then((result) => {
        const imageUrl = result.url;
        const data = { id: req.body.id, imageUrl };
        updateAvatar(data);
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Success", data: { imageUrl } });
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Error", data: { err } })
      );
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Error" });
  }
});
```

So right now my url after upload image to cloudinary look like this :

> https://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617941466/zwpbarfxvd94olczjjpa.png

and I want to make the url like this:

> https://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617941466/UserAvatar/zwpbarfxvd94olczjjpa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `folder` as part of the optional parameters for the `upload()` method call to indicate in which folder the asset should be stored in.

For example, updating the method call to Cloudinary like so:

```
cloudinary.uploader
   .upload(
     newFile,
     {
       folder: "UserAvatar"
     }
   )
```

All other upload parameters can be found in the following section of the documentation:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method